# Is there any way I can save my internet favorites where I can see them from any computer?

Tags: bookmarks

I have many favorites sites that I need to link to from different computers, is there any way other than save it to jump drive and carry it with me.
Is there any public site site were I can save them at?

Comment: The Chrome browser has this built in...

Comment: Mac OS X Safari and iCloud does this, too.

Comment: The Opera browser also have an option built-in (Opera Link).

Comment: -1, question does not show research effort.

Comment: Firefox has this built in

Comment: Internet Explorer bookmarks are just files in the user's profile under *Favorites*. Use any file syncing solution.

Comment: -2 if I could, as the question is also *unclear* as to be almost unanswerable: User failed to specify OS(es), browser(s), and their versions.

Comment: @DanielBeck, perhaps OP wanted an OS/browser independent solution? You're right thought, they could've stood to specify more of that though.

Comment: @EricR Writing "all of them" is also *specifying OS(es), browser(s), and their versions.* But it's also missing.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of long-time users are wary of the recent changes made under new ownership, but [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) has been around for a long time and has served me well.

It's free.

Since it's a website, you can pretty much access it from anywhere. Unless you work for a big corporation -- they mostly still block it these days.

You can keep a lot of links -- a lot more than you'd ever want to put in a browser bookmark list. I have over a thousand.

And you can see other people's links and comments, so you can find the most popular ones for specified topics.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox this is part of the standard browser, no third party solution required.

[How to sync Firefox settings between computers](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/How%20to%20sync%20Firefox%20settings%20between%20computers)

Answer (score 0):

I like Chrome for just that reason. Anywhere you log-in you have your whole world of internet just like at home...  and they have a "Feedly" extension that adds to my being able to see the sites I like at a glance...